# how to get the msi file instead of exe file with installshield 2011

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, exe

I begin to use InstallShield 2011 to create my installers (they must be files .msi). Using a basic msi project I finally get a setup.exe. My reference was this thread: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=171096, I did what the post says, except the media type (default is network image), but the method doesn't work. I'm using the premier trial version, could that be the reason? Or what is exactly the process? Help please, thanks.

Comment: What media type are you using?

Answer (score 4):

There are certain scenarios ( such as adding prereqs, authoring multiple languages and/or multiple instances ) that require the use of setup.exe.   Run the the release wizard and you should see a screen that asks if you want to generate a setup.exe or not.   Uncheck it if you can.   If you can't, you'll have to see what you added that requires it to be enabled and then choose from there.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the compressed option

(Installation Designer/Media/Releases)
Select the Release Image you want, go into it's "build" tab, set compression to uncompressed.

The result will be that instead of a setup.exe file you will have a Disk1 folder containing the .msi (Note that you need the whole folder for the installation)

Answer (score 2):

Please see "Functionality Notes for the Evaluation Version of InstallShield” http://support.installshield.com/kb/view.asp?articleid=Q200900

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Releases -> Prepare for Release**. On left-hand side select the way your file is generated e.g SingleImage or DVD. On the right, go to **Setup.exe tab** and select **No** for **Setup Launcher**.